# Exporting C/C++ library to Go

Tags: c++, c, go, binding

I'm working on a personal poker app, with a backend in Go for performances reasons, I struggle to bind the library https://github.com/HenryRLee/PokerHandEvaluator (You can find the C++ implementation in cpp directory) to Go. I know that we can define CFLAGS, CXX_FLAGS, etc for the compiler and import C to make the binding and use the cpp library with Go. But, to be honest, I'm not used to C/C++ compiler, and I don't know how to make the binding work. I tried a lot of flags, but I did not find a way to make it work. Is it even possible?

EDIT:

An example of what I tried to import the C interface :

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/PokerHandEvaluator/cpp/build -lphevaluator
// #cgo CFLAGS:  -I${SRCDIR}/PokerHandEvaluator/cpp/include
// #include "phevaluator/phevaluator.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.evaluate_7cards(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
}
```

The result by the go compiler when I run go run main.go

```
# runtime/internal/sys
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go:9:7: PtrSize redeclared in this block
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:24:38: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go:10:24: undefined: Uintreg
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go:16:7: StackGuardMultiplier redeclared in this block
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:27:74: previous declaration
```

EDIT(Resolved):
I tried this and it worked.
The previous error occured because my go installation was not clean. I re installed it and it worked.

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/PokerHandEvaluator/cpp/build -lpheval
// #cgo CFLAGS:  -I${SRCDIR}/PokerHandEvaluator/cpp/include
// #include "phevaluator/phevaluator.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    rank := C.evaluate_7cards(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    fmt.Println(rank)
}
```

Comment: The usual way is to write C++ code with `extern "C"` that hides the all C++ machinery from the caller. This is quite a lot of work. Alternatively, you could try using SWIG to adapt the C++ library to Go, but it is still pretty painful. (you need to have a mental model of C++ type maps to Go)

Comment: Oh wait, [there is a small C interface as well](https://github.com/HenryRLee/PokerHandEvaluator/blob/master/cpp/include/phevaluator/phevaluator.h#L62-L71). If that suffices for you, that should be fairly trivial to bind to Go.

Comment: The small C interface is sufficient, as I will make an adapter, but i also tried to import it but no way to make it work, do u have an example of how to make it work ? Not necessarly with this project but finding good resources is quite difficult as C and C++ are languages I did not touch for a very long time

Comment: Did you read the golang documentation on interfacing with and embedding C libraries? You don't really need to know C or C++ for this beyond what the types mean.

Comment: I have already read the documentation of course. I edited with what I tried